# Push notification is not showing 2kb in ios 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

Check this following push notification response. I have passed longer text in the "alert", but it is cut to "Riddham Pan". It exceeds the limit of payload.

Can any one please tell me how they counted 256 bytes in the following notification.

I am checking in ios 9 so limit should be 2kb. Do I have to do any custom settings in code for getting the notification upto 2kb length?

```
{
    EmailID = "";
    Message = "";
    NotificationType = Offline;
    RefId = 0;
    RefType = "3f588d5b-dbbd-4a65-b800-d863f8eb684d@conference.dev.time.appleapps.in";
    UserName = New1;
    aps =     {
        alert = "Riddham Pan";
        badge = 2;
        "content-available" = 1;
        sound = "sms-received5.caf";
    };
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your JSON might be invalid, have you checked it?

Comment: This is invalid JSON.

Comment: You should have commas (,) where you have semi-colons (;) at the end of lines.

Answer (score 0):

The JSON is invalid. If payload limit exceeds than 2kb notification would not be handled. From Apple docs

> Apple Push Notification service refuses any notification that exceeds this limit.
>   [Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html)

Since you are receiving notifications this means your payload limit is not exceeding but JSON format is invalid.